# show filename with matching word from grep only

Tags: grep, find, match, ksh

I am trying to find which words happened in logfiles plus show the logfilename for anything that matches following pattern:

```
'BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00'
```

so if file dummylogfile.log contains BA10002 I would like to get a result such as:

dummylogfile.log:BA10002

it is totally fine if the logfile shows up twice for duplicate matches.

the closest I got is:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.err' -exec grep -l 'BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00' {} \+);do printf $f;printf ':';grep -o  'BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00' $f;done
```

but this gives things like:

```
./register-05-14-11-53-59_24154.err:BA10
BA10
./register_mdw_files_2020-05-14-11-54-32_24429.err:BA10
BA10
./process_tables.2020-05-18-11-18-09_11428.err:BA30
./status_load_2020-05-18-11-35-31_9185.err:BA30
```

so,
1) there are empty lines with only the second match and
2) the full match (e.g., BA10004) is not shown.

thanks for the help

Comment: Option `-H` of GNU grep might help.

Comment: cool, thanks!! that is very close to the answer already (not quite I just realize, but very helpful indeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can pass to `grep`:

- **`-H`:** This will report the filename and the match
- **`-o`:** only show the match, not the full line
- **`-w`:** The match must represent a full word (string build from `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

If we look at your regex, you use `BA01`, this will match only `BA01` which can appear anywhere in the text, also mid word. If you want the regex to match a full word, it should read `BA01[[:alnum:]_]*` which adds any sequence of word-constituent characters (equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`). You can test this with

```
$ echo "foo BA01234 barBA012" | grep -Ho "BA01"
(standard input):BA01
(standard input):BA01
$ echo "foo BA01234 barBA012" | grep -How "BA01" 
$ echo "foo BA01234 barBA012" | grep -How "BA01[[:alnum:]_]*" 
(standard input):BA01234
```

So your `grep` should look like

```
grep -How "\('BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00'\)[[:alnum:]_]*" *.err
```

Comment: perfect, that's it, thanks!! (ps bonus question - how to include the filename in the return value without the awkward loop that I used?)

Answer (score 0):

From your example it seems that all files are in one directory. So the following works right away:

```
grep -l 'BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00' *.err
```

If the files are in different directories:

```
find . -name '*.err' -print | xargs -I {} grep 'BA10\|BA20\|BA21\|BA30\|BA31\|BA00' {} /dev/null
```

Explanation: the addition of **/dev/null** to the filename {} forces grep to report the matching filename

Comment: hi @monok, thanks, but see the accepted answer - the issue was not the grepping, but finding the full word back